# Why does my Jekyll image asset only show on localhost?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have this asset on my Jekyll blog: https://github.com/misingnoglic/misingnoglic.github.io/blob/master/assets/blog_images/face.jpg

However, the URL returns a 404: https://aryaboudaie.com/assets/blog_images/face.jpg

Similar images show up on my website however, e.g.

https://github.com/misingnoglic/misingnoglic.github.io/blob/master/assets/blog_images/flask/repl_click.png

https://aryaboudaie.com/assets/blog_images/flask/repl_click.png

And the most annoying part is that the image shows up locally, so I can't debug this really without pushing to Github. I've had previous issues where because I'm on windows, my computer didn't care about case sensitivity while github did, but everything is the correct case this time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link works fine for me.  Try refreshing your cache?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks Seth!

Comment: And you can approve @seth answer.